# Ediff location pane

Tags: window, ediff

Is there a way to create something similar to the location pane from win merge in ediff?

[image]

Not having this is about the only reason I use win merged instead of ediff.

Comment: A good place to start might be minimap mode [available from elpa](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/minimap.html)

Comment: Since this isn't likely to ever work in terminal version of Emacs, you might get better results by generating XBM or BMP (these are fairly simple formats, one can generate these without specialized software).

Comment: Not what you are requesting, but just to check: You do know about (1) line-number indication in the mode line and (2) a vertical scroll bar indicates the relative buffer position, right?